# dropdown list using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

i have created 1 drop-down list when i click the value it should remove from dropdown n store in another field..
And when i double click the value in that field it should go back to the drown list.

give me some idea please

Comment: What is the problem?  Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try searching and exploring JQuery examples for this.

Comment: I have just started i was thinking wheather to use java script or jquery.. ok thanks i will tey with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial example is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function handleClick(e, listElement) {

  // Get the element that was clicked on
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // If the element has class 'item' ...
  if (el && /item/.test(el.className)) {

    // Move it from its current list to the other one
    if (listElement.id == 'list-0') {
      document.getElementById('list-1').appendChild(el);

    } else {
      document.getElementById('list-0').appendChild(el);
    }
  }
}

</script>

<ul id="list-0" onclick="handleClick(event, this);">
  <li class="item">apple
  <li class="item">orange
  <li class="item">banana
</ul>

<ul id="list-1" onclick="handleClick(event, this);">
  <li>add stuff here...
</ul>
```

Of course there is an awful lot required to make the above anything like useful in a web page.